# Unpacking a dictionary and passing to a function as keyword parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, google-cloud-pubsub, argument-unpacking

I am trying in python to unpack some dict into some function:

I have a function that get `packet` as parameter (that should be dict)

```
def queue(self, packet):
    self.topic.publish(self.message, self.client, **packet)
```

and I call it this way:

```
queue({
        'an_item': 1,
        'a_key': 'value'
    })
```

the publish function, is in [3rd party api](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub/topic.py#L237) (Google Pub/Sub API) and from what I looked at source:

```
def publish(self, message, client=None, **attrs):
    ...
    message_data = {'data': message, 'attributes': attrs}
    message_ids = api.topic_publish(self.full_name, [message_data])
```

it's accepting **attrs in order to pass all keyword parameters into another function.

Currently.. my queue() function isn't working.

How, if possible, can I fix my `queue()` function to unpack the `packet` dict argument into something `publish()` will accept?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Some error messages I got.

for:

```
def queue(self, packet):
    self.topic.publish(self.message, self.client, **packet)
```

I get: `TypeError: 1 has type <class 'int'>, but expected one of: (<class 'bytes'>, <class 'str'>)`

---

for:

```
def queue(self, packet):
    self.topic.publish(self.message, self.client, packet)
```

I get: `publish() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

---

for:

```
def queue(self, **packet):
    self.topic.publish(self.message, self.client, packet)
```

I get: `TypeError: queue() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

---

and for:

```
def queue(self, *packet):
    self.topic.publish(self.message, self.client, packet)
```

I get: `TypeError: publish() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

---

EDIT 2:

as @gall suggested correctly, it is the data I was sending and there is no problem with the unpacking. with this function:

```
def queue(self, packet):
    self.topic.publish(self.message, self.client, **packet)
```

It works when I call it with strings only:

```
queue({
        'an_item': '1',
        'a_key': 'value'
    })
```

Thank you all!

Comment: How is your function not working, could you give an error message?

Comment: Yes @JonasAdler . Thank you. I'll add error message example for what I've tried until now

Comment: what does `self.topic` refer to? an instance of the `Topic` class or just the class itself?

Comment: @danidee some object in google's sub/pub api that let you get access to publish() function for pub/sub channel.

Comment: In the docstring of ``publish`` it says ``:type attrs: dict (string -> string)`` but you seem to have one value as an int in your example. Could it be the problem? The way you call it seems fine otherwise.

Comment: @Gall. Yes! trying to send {
            'an_item': '1',
            'a_key': 'value'
        } works. does it mean I can't pass int as argument? mm.. so I guess the unpack actually worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docstring of [publish](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/7fa089cb2b3a67de9fc454fb25c9c1e99760141e/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub/topic.py#L263-L264), `attr` must be a `string -> string` dict.

You can fix the issue by replacing

```
queue({
    'an_item': 1,
    'a_key': 'value'
})
```

with purely string arguments, e.g.

```
queue({
    'an_item': '1',
    'a_key': 'value'
})
```

It seems your issue had nothing to do with dictionary unpacking.